# Unable to POST to Grafana using Python3 module requests

Tags: python-requests, python-3.4, grafana

I'm trying to create a dashboard on Grafana using their backend API. I first test that my API token is set up by using GET and successfully get a return code of 200(shown below). I then try to use POST to create a simple dashboard but I keep getting a return code of 400. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the payload I'm trying to send, but I have been unable to figure it out. Here is the link to the example page I'm using for their JSON format. http://docs.grafana.org/reference/http_api/

```
import requests


headers = {"Accept": "application/json","Content-Type": "application/json" ,"Authorization": "Bearer xxx"}

r = requests.get("http://www.localhost",headers=headers)
print(r.text)
print(r.status_code)



dashboard = {"id": None,
             "title": "API_dashboard_test",
             "tags": "[CL-5]",
             "timezone": "browser",
             "rows":"[{}]",
             "schemaVersion": 6,
             "version": 0
             }
payload = {"dashboard": "%s" % dashboard}
url = "http://www.localhost/api/dashboards/db"

p = requests.post(url,headers=headers, data=payload)
print(p)
print(p.status_code)
print(p.text)
```

OUTPUT:

```
200
<Response [400]>
400
[{"classification":"DeserializationError","message":"invalid character 'd' looking for beginning of value"},{"fieldNames":["Dashboard"],"classification":"RequiredError","message":"Required"}]
```

Comment: `payload = {"dashboard": dashboard}`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39954475/post-request-works-in-postman-but-not-in-python/39954514#39954514,

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That was one issue I was having. I also needed to change the syntax for the rest of my arguments that was incorrectly quoted along with converting the python object to a json string as sub has shown below, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your object is not an actual json object.

You can use post method with json=YOUR_PYTHON_OBJECT

So to fix your code, change your dictionary to use just a regular python dictionary, use json=payload, rather than data=payload.

So refactoring your code, you will have:

```
import requests
headers = {"Accept": "application/json",
           "Content-Type": "application/json",
           "Authorization": "Bearer xxx"
           }

r = requests.get("http://www.localhost", headers=headers)
print(r.text)
print(r.status_code)

dashboard = {"id": None,
             "title": "API_dashboard_test",
             "tags": ["CL-5"],
             "timezone": "browser",
             "rows": [{}],
             "schemaVersion": 6,
             "version": 0
             }
payload = {"dashboard": dashboard}
url = "http://www.localhost/api/dashboards/db"

p = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
print(p)
print(p.status_code)
print(p.text)
```

Note the differences in dashboard, for example, "rows" was changed from "[{}]" to just [{}] so that it is a python object (list with empty dictionary), rather than a string.

The output is

```
200
<Response [200]>
200
{"slug":"api_dashboard_test","status":"success","version":0}
```